# implement in app update FLEXIBLE click on button and show the process in round process bar

Tags: java, xml

I'm using Android Play Core Library's new feature In-App Updates. So the documentation says that for a Flexible In-App Update, I need an InstallStateUpdatedListener which would listen for when the update is downloaded in the background, and then we need to show a UI or in my case a layout to the user, describing that the user now needs to install the already downloaded update. This works fine when I'm in the foreground for the whole time, but when I go to the background and its show on progessbar before the in-app update is downloaded and then return to the foreground of the app after some time, my app automatically gets updated without showing any UI to the user asking them to install the update. This should not happen ideally as per the docs.